# Drupal Custom Module Results to 404

Tags: drupal-7, url-routing

I'm having a really weird error right now. This was working fine a moment ago, but now when I access the url it gives the 404 error "Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Here is my custom url

```
$items['timefie/obj/list/%'] = array(
    'title' => t('List Record'),
    'page arguments' => array(3),
    'page callback' => 'timefie_record_list',
    'access arguments' => array(2,3),
    'access callback' => 'timefie_user_access',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK // PLS IGNORE THIS LINE, I WAS DEBUGGING THEN
);
```

[image]

I have cleared my cache already many times to no avail.
I have also back-tracked my last few movements to try put them back on their previous configuration namely (logintobbogan, site information).

Another pointer, I tried to create a Menu links of this URL in admin/structure/menu/item and it seems it accepts it as valid but he is not validating the last URL argument '%' see second picture...[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This 404 error is not from Drupal it's from your apache server, so i recommend that you check that you have clean URLs enabled also it will be a good idea to create a virtual host for your site because i think localhos/timefie is causing problems for you. then try again if you still have the same error check the page that redirected you to this page as there could be a broken link or check the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

The requested URL "localhost/timefie/timefie/obj/list/transaction" is not found because there is some  issue related to local host configuration. The URL should be "localhost/timefie/obj/list/transaction".

Comment: The way I understand it my previous setup is that I have a single host which root is in /var/www/ and folder inside it is my 'timefie' a drupal installation (I have multiple folder in that by the way) the 'timefie/timefie' is ok as I have declared it that way in my MENU module. I've made a lot of config when I setup my installation, didn't understand some of it but it worked, so I left it that way. Now that I understand it has to be in multiple virtuahl host, what I did is reinstall the apache and found online a tutotrial in setting it up properly. It working now. Thank you for your effort :D

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your effort, I ended up re-installing my apache and php, and found a tutorial to properly setup it in Multiple Virtual Hosts. I'm new to ubuntu so it takes a lot of effort for me to understand whats going on whenever theres an error. Thaks again.